# OAuth Verification for drive api

Tags: react-native, google-oauth

So, I'm preparing my React Native app for verification and it uses 2 scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly

Currently, I ask the user to input the share link of a drive file and then access that to get it's file name and contents. However I have read about Google Picker (https://workspace.google.com/blog/product-announcements/enhancing-security-controls-for-google-drive-third-party-apps)  being encouraged and was wondering if anyone has any experience of getting verified without that? Is the Google Picker the only way out for such a use case?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance :D